# .htaccess password protection - is design possible?

Tags: .htaccess

Everyone knows about the .htaccess / .htpasswd password protection for files or directories. I've looked on the internet without success for a way to edit the 'Design' of that coding. Right now, when you use that, you'll get prompted with the basic browser window to enter a username and password. Is there a way that username / password login form be integrated into a webpage with a design OR any way to design that prompt?

Unsure if I'm understandable at all... let me know if you require more clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: No. That's called HTTP "basic" auth and is kept as simple & dependable as possible.

Comment: If the username and password can be included in the initial request for the protected resource then sure, you can create any login prompt you want and use those credentials in that request.  I know HTTP allows for sending a username and password on the request itself, though that's kind of a bad idea in terms of security.  But I'm not 100% sure if it's any less secure than Basic Auth is in the first place.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Do you guys consider .htaccess password protection secure at all? Any suggestions for a similar, simple, coding that could be integrated in a webpage? I thought of a simple php page with md5 encryption directly into code, but if a 'hacker' gets that php file, he can easily revert the md5 encryption ...

Comment: @Anthony: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php  Basic auth isn't very secure, no.  MD5 isn't great either.  And if an attacker can reverse your passwords from your code then you've done something *very* wrong.

Comment: Thank you david. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

See comments below initial question.

Answer : No it is not possible, if we keep the basic .htaccess auth. It might be possible using HTTP requests but it won't be as secure.